# Make input disappear when I click on it again

Tags: javascript, html

How do I make it so that when I enter something in an input field, and I unselect/click out of the field and then click on the input field again the text/input I wrote disappears?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the `focus` listener to the input and clear the value everytime that event is launched.

Fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/dfa6m42e/1/

```js
let inp = document.querySelector('#myInput')

inp.addEventListener('focus', () => {
  inp.value = '';
})
```

```html
<input type="text" id='myInput'>
```

Comment: While it works, this is a downvote for using jQuery when it's a simple question.

Comment: @KentondeJong Thanks for the feedback, I edited the answer to use vanilla JS

Comment: I changed to an upvote. I've been using jQuery since 2011. It's a tough habit to stop using.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure that you need to have a blur event. You can add something like this wherever you are initiating your event listeners.

```
var inputElement = document.getElementById("myinputelement");
inputElement.addEventListener("focus", function(e) {
  this.value="";
})
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
let input = document.querySelector('input');
input.onclick = function(){ input.value = ''; };
```

Comment: @Spectric Maybe the person didn't like the "old" syntax. Who knows!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the blur event to add a focus event

```
var myInput = ...;
myInput.addEventListener("blur", function(e) {
  myInput.removeEventListener("blur", this);
  myInput.addEventListener("focus", function(e) {
    myInput.value = "";
  }
}
```